# SQL query for finding record with certain values that has different id in same table

Tags: sql, oracle

i have an example table like this named a.

```
A_ID          |B_ID         |C_ID        |NUMBER      |REFERENCE           |
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
3-14SW-958    |3-13M7-3271  |3-16XW-3623 |02220537890 |131165138672        |
3-14SW-958    |3-152G-1599  |3-15NH-3456 |02220537890 |131165138672        |
3-14MW-2720   |3-14V0-3580  |3-15IE-2736 |02287528203 |131183102805        |
3-14MW-2720   |3-16LT-2845  |3-13WH-3111 |02287528203 |131183102805        |
3-14SW-958    |3-152G-1599  |3-15NH-3456 |131165138672|02220537890         |
3-14MW-2720   |3-14V0-3580  |3-15IE-2736 |131183102805|02287528203         |
```

Within this table, i want result that the number are referenced but has different values B_ID and C_ID like this

```
|B_ID         |C_ID        |NUMBER      |REFERENCE           |
|3-13M7-3271  |3-16XW-3623 |02220537890 |131165138672        |
|3-16LT-2845  |3-13WH-3111 |02287528203 |131183102805        |
```

How would you express this in a SQL query? I was thinking self join but i still cant get it

this is what i mean referenced

```
|NUMBER      |REFERENCE           |COUNT(*)|
|02220537890 |131165138672        |2       |
|131165138672|02220537890         |1       |
```

using max or min function wont get it

**Many thanks in advance**

Comment: please explain the logic.

Comment: certain values you mean is NUMBER or REFERENCE or the combination of these 2 columns?

Comment: You neglected to tell us the logic by which we get from your starting table to the output.  Please include that too.

Comment: B_ID that has different values with their reference but has same number

Comment: What determines which of the two `C_ID` values gets reported?

Comment: Could you please elaborate the logic behind the 2nd output table? Do you only want the first matching record from the 1st table or something?

Comment: @Nava Bogatee there you go

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
select b_id, c_id, n, r from tmp_test where b_id in (
  select max(b_id) from tmp_test group by n having count(1)>1
);
```

to extract unique `NUMBER`s and `REF`s:

```
select n, r from tmp_test group by n, r having count(1)>1
```

Comment: i dont think using max() function would solve it
its because there's b_id that has small values with their ref in same num

Comment: @NKagami choose the aggregation function according to your logic then. `min`, `max`, even more.

Comment: What if the values in b_id and c_id is like this?

<pre>
|B_ID         |C_ID        |NUMBER      |REFERENCE           |
|3-13M7-3271  |3-16XW-3623 |02220537890 |131165138672        |
|3-16LT-2845  |3-13WH-3111 |02287528203 |131183102805        |
</pre>

Comment: @NKagami you have one number `02220537890` and two different `B_ID` (and `C_ID`). You have to choose one `B_ID` ( or `C_ID`) from these two. The bigger, smaller or the first? It depends on what your business logic is.

Comment: i want to get number 02220537890 that has different b_id (and c_id) on same reference
i just want to get rid double number that has different b_id and c_id on same reference

Comment: @NKagami you only need unique `NUMBER`s (along with `REF`) ?

Comment: yeah unique number that has referenced but different b_id and s_id

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the `GROUP BY` and `HAVING` as follows:

```
SELECT MAX(B_ID) AS B_ID,
       MAX(C_ID) AS C_ID, 
       NUMBER, 
       REFERENCE 
FROM YOUR_TABLE
GROUP BY A_ID, NUMBER, REFERENCE
HAVING COUNT(1) > 1;
```

Note: Avoid using the oracle reserved keywords as the name of the columns (In you case, `NUMBER` and `REFERENCE` should be avoided as the column names)

Comment: why using max() function?
what if there's smaller values but has double number and ref

Comment: Used MAX as it was satisfying the sample data and expected output.

Comment: What if the values in b_id and c_id is like this?

<pre>
|B_ID         |C_ID        |NUMBER      |REFERENCE           |
|3-13M7-3271  |3-16XW-3623 |02220537890 |131165138672        |
|3-16LT-2845  |3-13WH-3111 |02287528203 |131183102805        |
</pre>

Comment: Then use appropriate aggregation function according to your requirement.

Comment: that's where i stuck

Answer (score 0):

> Within this table, i want result that the number are referenced but has different values B_ID and C_ID like this

You can use `EXISTS` :

```
SELECT t.*
FROM table t
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM table t1 WHERE t1.refrence = t.refrence AND t1.b_id <> t.b_id);
```

Comment: nope, the result are like this
3-14SW-958 3-13M7-3271 3-16XW-3623 02220537890 131165138672
3-14SW-958 3-152G-1599 3-15NH-3456 02220537890 131165138672
3-14MW-2720 3-14V0-3580 3-15IE-2736 02287528203 131183102805
3-14MW-2720 3-16LT-2845 3-13WH-3111 02287528203 131183102805

Answer (score 0):

Is it what you're looking for?

**SQL**

```
SELECT a.B_ID , a.C_ID ,a.`NUMBER` ,a.REFERENCE FROM Test a 
INNER JOIN  Test b
on a.REFERENCE = b.REFERENCE 
AND a.B_ID != b.B_ID 
AND a.C_ID !=b.C_ID
```

**OUTPUT**

```
B_ID       |C_ID       |NUMBER    |REFERENCE   |
-----------|-----------|----------|------------|
3-152G-1599|3-15NH-3456|2220537890|131165138672|
3-13M7-3271|3-16XW-3623|2220537890|131165138672|
3-16LT-2845|3-13WH-3111|2287528203|131183102805|
3-14V0-3580|3-15IE-2736|2287528203|131183102805|
```